# dojox.mobile: Custom ListItem widget: "... is not a constructor"

Tags: dojo, listitem, dojox.mobile

I want to create a custom ListItem widget for my dojox.mobile app. It works if i use it in my HTML Code, but it throws a TypeError if i try to use it programmatically.

This is the JS-Code for my custom ListItem:

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojox/mobile/ListItem"], function(declare, domConstruct, ListItem){

var LabeledInputListItem = declare("myapp.LabeledInputListItem", ListItem, {

    labelText: "",
    placeholder: "",
    value: "",

    _setItemLabelAttr: function(val) {
        this.labelText = val;
        this.qDescSpan.innerHTML = val;
    },

    _setPlaceholderAttr: function(val) {
        this.placeholder = val;
    },

    _setValueAttr: function(val) {
        this.value = val;
    },

    startup: function(){
        if(this._started){ return; }

    },

    constructor: function(params) {
        this.placeholder = params.placeholder;
        this.labelText = params.labelText;
        this.valu = params.value;
    },

    buildRendering: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);

        this.qDescDiv = domConstruct.create("div", {className: "tableItemDescription", id: "asd"}, this.labelNode, "before");
        this.qDescSpan = domConstruct.create("span", null, this.qDescDiv, "first");

        this.qInputDiv = domConstruct.create("div", {className: "tableItemInput"}, this.qDescDiv, "after");
        this.qInputText = domConstruct.create("input", {className: "mblTextBox sessionTextbox", placeholder: this.placeholder, value: this.value}, this.qInputDiv, "first");
        console.log(this.labelText, this.placeholder, this.value);
    },

});

return LabeledInputListItem;  });
```

I can use this custom ListItem in my html Code like this:

```
<li data-dojo-type="myapp/LabeledInputListItem" data-dojo-props="itemLabel: 'asdasd', placeholder: 'placeholder', value: 'value'"></li>
```

However, if I try to create my custom ListItem programmatically it results in the following error:

```
TypeError: myapp.LabeledInputListItem is not a constructor

var childWidget = new myapp.LabeledInputListItem({placeholder: "placeholder"});
```

Does anybody know what i'm missing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: As @edurocher says, you shouldn't use the global style of instantiation any more. What happens if you instead do `require(["myapp/LabeledInputListItem"], function(LabeledInputListItem) { new LabeledInputListItem({placeholder: "placeholder"}); });`? Note that the class should be in `myapp/LabeledInputListItem.js`.

Answer (score 1):

The only (obvious) reason I can think of would be that you did not require the module?
By the way Dojo is now moving towards a "no globals" approach, so it may be better to not give an explicit id to your class, and use the value of the AMD module instead of the global myapp.LabeledInputListItem.